# My state looks like it's not an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement a store without NgRx and I have made a function in my `store.ts` that can select every Object I want, like in NgRx:

```js
export interface State {
  user: User | undefined;
  meals: Meal | undefined;
  [key: string]: any;
}

const state: State = {
  user: undefined,
  meals: undefined,
};

select<T>(name: string): Observable<T> {
  return this.store.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((state) => state[name])
  );
}
```

In my component I try to select my meal:

```js
export class MealsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  meals$ = Observable<Meal[]>;
  subscription!: Subscription;

  constructor(private mealService: MealService, private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.mealService.meal$.subscribe();
    this.meals$ = this.store.select<Meal[]>('meals');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is my error message :

> Type 'Observable<Meal[]>' is missing the following properties from type '{ new (subscribe?: ((this: Observable<Meal[]>, subscriber: Subscriber<Meal[]>) => TeardownLogic) | undefined): Observable<Meal[]>; prototype: Observable<...>; create: (...args: any[]) => any; }': prototype, createts(2739)

To summarize: I have tried to select an Observable, it don't work and I don't understand the error message.

I don't know if I am intelligible in my question, if not let me know. I really appreciate all the answers I can get.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It's hard to see what the issue is here without seeing a bit more of your code - an example StackBlitz reproducing the issue would be ideal.

Comment: As a first suggestion: does adding an `as Observable<Meal[]>` after your `this.store.select...` call do anything?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer ! I cant do an as observable<MEAL[]> because i want it to be generic but as observable<any[]> don't work either. I try to use the angular firebase but it has changed so much and documentation is inexistant... i wii try to make you a stackblitz project tommorrow thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a way to make all that working :

```
select(name: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.store.pipe(map((value) => value[name as keyof State]));
  }
```

That was not easy to find but it actually work...

Thnak you for all your answer

Comment: Hey @djbone, if this was the answer to your question don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an mistake  `meals$ = Observable<Meal[]>;`

Type of `meals$` is derived from value, change it as `meals$: Observable<Meal[]>;`

Comment: yes it's a typo error sorry but my code still dont work. I just want to select a value from an object passing a string to my function select like : select('meals') but i don't think it works with  map((state) => state[name]. It worked when pluck was not depreciated : select<T>(name: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.store.pluck(name);
  }